# Nesting HTTP GET parameters (request within a request)

Tags: http, url, parameters, get, nested

I want to call a JSP with GET parameters within the GET parameter of a parent JSP.  The URL for this would be `http://server/getMap.jsp?lat=30&lon=-90&name=http://server/getName.jsp?lat1=30&lon1=-90`

`getName.jsp` will return a string that goes in the `name` parameter of `getMap.jsp`.

I think the problem here is that `&lon1=-90` at the end of the URL will be given to `getMap.jsp` instead of `getName.jsp`.  **Is there a way to distinguish which GET parameter goes to which URL?**

One idea I had was to encode the second URL (e.g. `=` -> `%3D` and `&` -> `%26`) but that didn't work out well.  My best idea so far is to allow only one parameter in the second URL, comma-delimited.  So I'll have `http://server/getMap.jsp?lat=30&lon=-90&name=http://server/getName.jsp?params=30,-90` and leave it up to `getName.jsp` to parse its variables.  This way I leave the `&` alone.

**NOTE** - I know I can approach this problem from a completely different angle and avoid nested URLs altogether, but I still wonder (for the sake of knowledge!) if this is possible or if anyone has done it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been done a lot, especially with ad serving technologies and URL redirects

But an encoded URL should just work fine. You need to completely encode it tho. A generator can be found [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

So this:
http://server/getMap.jsp?lat=30&lon=-90&name=http://server/getName.jsp?lat1=30&lon1=-90

becomes this: http://server/getMap.jsp?lat=30&lon=-90&name=http%3A%2F%2Fserver%2FgetName.jsp%3Flat1%3D30%26lon1%3D-90

I am sure that jsp has a function for this. Look for "urlencode". Your JSP will see the contents of the GET-Variable "name" as the unencoded string: "http://server/getName.jsp?lat1=30&lon1=-90"